# Looping through full year with JavaScript without showing the time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a kind of resource planning manager basically kind of a calendar. And I need to loop through a full year.

I have the following code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 365; x++){
    var today = new Date(2015, 01, x);
    document.write(today + "<br />");
}
```

Its kind of what I want but then I just want to show the day, the date, the month and the year, now it also shows the time. How to hide the time. Check this link to see my result (http://gyazo.com/3df91f5292072a54415d13b2ccca4922)

Comment: Think you're looking for this: [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the part of the date you need. For example:

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

function formatDate(date) {
 var month = date.getUTCMonth() +1;
 var dayNumber = date.getUTCDate();
 var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
 var day = date.getUTCDay();
 return year + "-" + month + "-" + dayNumber + " " + weekday[day];
}
```

So you code becomes:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 365; x++){
    var today = formatDate(new Date(2015, 01, x));
    document.write(today + "<br />");
}
```

P.S. note the +1 when calculating the month.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/ajsv5ge4/

Comment: thanks for the code it works but i would also like to show the day like Mo, Tu, We, etc...

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response. i updated the code with the array of weekday but when i run it i get an error in console saying that : Uncaught TypeError: date.getUTCFullYear is not a function ...

Comment: @GY22 fixed. I accidentally use the same name for the number of date

Answer (score 0):

You can use some lib like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY')
```